# rabbitmq consumer with multiple channels causing duplicate messages

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

Is it possible in Rabbitmq for a scenario where a single thread with multiple channels to consume messages from a single queue and have the same message consumed twice? We have code passed from a previous developer which is in a library that seems to find duplicate messages in a queue. However when using a simple single consumer with single channel to consume the same queue, it is quite evident there are no duplicate messages in the queue. This is causing some heated arguments and would be easily solvable if we could debug the other party's code but thi is not possible due to some licensing issue.

In all the years using rabbitmq and .NEt consumers we have not encountered this. Is there reason to this madness to prove our point?

Comment: This `single thread with multiple channels to consume messages from a single queue` makes absolutely no sense. Before I continue, I just wanted to check if this is the part that you can debug/change or not?

Answer (score 1):

Since the server is not single-threaded, this sounds plausible and implementation dependent.

However, Having two channels bound to the same queue on a single-threaded consumer does not make any sense to me.